# Query a database and return a 'total' for each location based on a search parameter

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, knex.js

I'm creating an API for a database, and I'm currently trying to make a search endpoint that takes the search parameter and returns all 'days' and a total of occurrences for that parameter. E.g. (Columns = degrees) (Rows = days in a year), if the parameter was 30 degrees I want to select the 30 degree column and return a total of occasions in which a day hit 30 degrees. So something like: Monday: 0:, Tuesday 10, Wednesday: 8, etc.

So far I've selected the data I want to use based on the parameter but I can't get it to sum each day. My attempts so far have either been a list of 365 days, or a sum of all the days. I understand that I would have to sum the Temp param but I can't work out how to do it so that I end up with each days total.

Current function:

```
router.get('/search/:Temp', func(req, res) {
    req.temps.from('days').select('weekDay', req.params.Temp)
    .then((columns)=> {
        res.json({'Search Result': rows)
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand right, you have a table that looks something like this:

```
Id  Date        WeekDay     Temperature
----------------------------------------
1   2019-05-30  Thursday    25
2   2019-05-29  Wednesday   30
3   2019-05-28  Tuesday     30
4   2019-05-27  Monday      25
5   2019-05-26  Sunday      25
6   2019-05-25  Saturday    26
7   2019-05-24  Friday      27
8   2019-05-23  Thursday    25
9   2019-05-22  Wednesday   25
10  2019-05-21  Tuesday     30
11  2019-05-20  Monday      30
12  2019-05-19  Sunday      25
13  2019-05-18  Saturday    26
14  2019-05-17  Friday      25
15  2019-05-16  Thursday    25
```

And you want to have a result that looks something like this, given a temperature:

```
WeekDay     Occurences
-----------------------
Friday      1
Monday      1
Sunday      2
Thursday    3
Wednesday   1
```

You have to use the `GROUP BY`. In raw SQL it can be written like this:

```sql
SELECT
      WeekDay
    , COUNT(Temperature) AS Occurences
FROM Temperatures
WHERE Temperature = 25
GROUP BY WeekDay
```

The temperature here is 25. The `GROUP BY` clause groups all the weekdays together. When you group things together, you must also use aggregate functions that decides how the rows are grouped together. In this case, `COUNT()` is the aggregate function to use.

Using Knex, it should look something like this:

```
knex
  .select('WeekDay', knex.raw('COUNT(Temperature)'))
  .from('Temperatures')
  .where('Temperature', 25)
  .groupBy('WeekDay')
```

Comment: Works perfectly, I had to alter a tiny bit as it turned out I needed data displayed from another table as well so had to incorporate a join afterwards. But works as intended thanks